# NavigationManager.StartNavigation return INVALID_PARAMETERS

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, here-maps-rest

I'm using HereMaps Sdk for navigation and route calculations.
When I try to start a navigation or simulation I get error from INVALID_PARAMETERS...

I can not identify the problem to be able to solve.
I already have my routes configured and my map added to the
NavigationManager

I am using the example of the own nokia in their github as base.

https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/blob/master/turn-by-turn-navigation/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
    //OnEngineInitListener...    
    NavigationManager.Instance.SetMap(mapFragment.Map);
NavigationManager.Instance.SetMapUpdateMode(NavigationManager.MapUpdateMode.Position);
    var nresult = NavigationManager.Instance.StartTracking();
```

//nresult return only INVALID_PARAMETERS and navigation dont start

Comment: What is the stack Trace of exception?

Comment: This is the problem. There's nothing on the stack.
Only the return of the INVALID_PARAMETERS method